# Is it possible to use IUIFramework::LoadUI to load a compiled markup file?

Tags: winapi, ribbon

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371471(v=vs.85).aspx) for this function reads:

*Loads the Windows Ribbon framework UI resource, **or compiled markup**, file.*

I have the compiled `.bml` file (via uicc.exe). However, I don't know what parameters to pass for `instance` and `resourceName` when calling `LoadUI`.

Comment: They refer to [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632583(v=vs.85).aspx) types of resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented, the [IUIFramework::LoadUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371471.aspx) call can in fact load a compiled, binary markup file. This file must be linked as a [user-defined resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054.aspx) into the binary image, identified through the *instance* argument. *resourceName* is the name of this resource. By default, UUIC.exe assigns the name `"APPLICATION_RIBBON"`.

Assuming a standard [UUIC.exe invocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316930.aspx)

> UICC.exe RibbonMarkup.xml RibbonMarkup.bml /header:RibbonIds.h /res:RibbonUI.rc

This produces a resource script file *RibbonUI.rc* with the following line

> APPLICATION_RIBBON    UIFILE    "RibbonMarkup.bml"

This is the resource script file that adds the compiled, binary markup file into the executable image. `"APPLICATION_RIBBON"` is the name of the resource, and you can change it to anything you see fit (as long as it doesn't collide with other user-defined resources of type *UIFILE*).

A complete guide can be found at [Creating a Ribbon Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316924.aspx).